# Exit current call stack Javascript

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I'd like to exit my current call stack in javascript, in order not to explode the call stack size, but I don't have access to the `setTimeout()` call ie:

the function `setTimeout`don't exist in my environment :)

I still need to exit the current call stack as I reach the call stack size limit.

The environment is "parse.com" and CloudCode Modules, if any one know what's running behind, that could help as well!

Any guess?

PS: It's not because the only thing you know is a web browser environment and DOM node manipulation or even worse Javascript that you need to -1 the question, this one is really pertinent. Not every function is implemented everywhere.
PS2: There's no source code attached as it's more a theoretical question than an applied question!

Comment: You're trying to fix recursion with setTimeout? I don't follow.

Comment: I understand the setTimeout call that in fact create a new call stack, I need to create that new call stack without having a call to setTimeout. `.call`, `.apply` change the execution scope, but the recursion is still there!

Comment: You can have "infinite stack" if your function is tail recursive with [this trick](https://gist.github.com/1697037)

Comment: Are you actually having problems with the size of the call stack?

Comment: We need more information about what you're doing, @vfloz.  So far this doesn't make sense.

Comment: More info, plz. Very confusing

Comment: Show your current javascript that you are trying to exit out of.

Comment: Yeah this is a callstack size  problem using async.js on parse.com Cloud Code,

Comment: More info: "by nature setTimeout(fn, 0) creates a new call stack" 
I need to have the same behaviour without calling setTimeout

Comment: @Esailija nice try, but this is not recursive as the functions are different on each calls, I really need to generate the same stack behavior of setTimeout( fn, 0), without setTimeout

Comment: hey! Keep it easy, there's no code to show! :)
This question is as dumb as possible: `setTimeout( fn, time)` has the property of exiting the current call stack, and start a new one.

As I don't have access to this `setTimeout` as it's not implemented in the environment i'm running in, I need an alternative that can exit the current call stack and spawn a new one...

Comment: setTimeout arranges for the callback to be executed asynchronously, and that call comes from a different call stack, yes.  What environment are you running in, if not a browser?  node.js?  Something else?

Comment: The environement I'm running in is (as written previously: parse.com CloudCode modules) that doesn't help! :)
The question if more fundamental on the javascript engine behaviours. If setTimeout exit the callstack, something else may do it as well!

Comment: What other asynchronous functions do you have access to? If any, maybe it's worth testing if they start a new call stack too?

Comment: @bfavaretto asynchronous functions by definition start a new call stack when they call your callback, they cannot continue the current call stack because that would block and it would not be asynchronous anymore :P

Comment: I don't know really... What do you think i could tell you which ones :)

Comment: Well for instance, if you have access to webworkers, you could create one solely for async callbacks

Comment: @Esailija That's what I was assuming, I guess I was just afraid of saying something silly :P

Comment: No web workers, unfortunately, there's no way on earth to tell a function with a call like `call`or `apply` to get executed on an other call stack?

Comment: @vfloz nope, you need another thread of execution or asynchronous call

Answer (score 3):

Javascript supports throwing exception objects (which can be anything really), which can exit the call stack as much as you want.  This MDN page might be of some use:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch

Comment: so I could try a try{ raise "exit callstack" }catch{ fnc() }, would I still be in the same call stack?

Comment: @vfloz yes, only if you don't catch the error will you exit the current call stack.

Comment: but not catching the error will result in my app to crash... this is to replace the async nextTick behaviour that uses setTimeout, I still need to catch the error somewhere to continue execution no?

Comment: @vfloz Well yes it will crash, but you did exit the call stack didn't you ;P On a serious thought, I don't know why this answer was even upvoted, it only makes sense if you read 4 first words of the question title

Comment: In a way it can make sense, if you go too deep in your call stack, you could throw on each tick, and catch at an upper level, the problem is callback inclusion here... that may be part of the solution after all :)

Comment: @vfloz you could just simply `return` on each tick just as well, it will have exactly the same effect.

Comment: I need to execute a callback on each tick :) that's the trick :)

Comment: @vfloz what do you mean what works? :P Is tick like node.js nextTick? Then you had access to async callbacks all this time? :P

Comment: in theory, tested in chrome `var final = function(){debugger;}; var middle = function(){ last()}; var last=function(){ throw final}; var start = function(){try{ middle(); }catch(fn){fn.apply(null)}}; start()` in the end, final is called from the start, so we escaladate the call stack back to the first caller; needs some more nail down to convert async.js

Comment: if you do the 'no throw' `var final = function(){debugger;}; var middle = function(){ last()}; var last=function(){final();}; var start = function(){try{ middle(); }catch(fn){fn.apply(null)}}; start()` you clearly see that final is executed at the bottom of the callstack :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20363/discussion-between-vfloz-and-esailija)

Comment: @vfloz yes but that is again no different from simple returns :P `var final = function () {
    debugger;
};
var middle = function () {
    return last()
};
var last = function () {
    return final;
};
var start = function () {
 middle().apply(null)
};
start()`

Answer (score 0):

Building on JayC's answer, you could keep a queue of functions to call, and run them in a loop. You would catch your "exit callstack" exception in the loop and run the next function.

The `nextTick` function would append its argument to the queue.

```
var queue = [];

function nextTick(f) {
    queue.push(f);
}

while (queue.length > 0) {
    try {
        var fun = queue.shift();
        fun();
    }
    catch (ex) {
        if (ex !== 'exit callstack') {
            // Handle "real" exceptions here
        }
    }
}
```

I haven't tested the code, but the idea should work. Of course, one caveat is that you can't use exception handling in your asynchronous functions (unless you check-for and re-throw  the "exit callstack" exception).

Comment: What is the try catch really adding here, I mean it would work the same without it provided no exceptions are thrown

Comment: @Esailija You're right, you wouldn't necessarily need it if you let each function run to the end. Throwing an exception just gives you the ability to break out of the current iteration at any point in the code. Catching exceptions would also be necessary if you want to always call the next queued function even when an exception is thrown.